# ffmpeg - Adding audio to a complex filter

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am using c# to programmatically write an ffmpeg command to crossfade a logo into a video. I also need to cut a couple of seconds into the video.

Here is the currently working ffmpeg command:
(No audio)

```
-y -loop 1 -t 3.2 -i "logo.png" -i "video.mp4" -r 29.97 -f lavfi -i color=black -filter_complex "
[0:v] scale=640:-1, crop=640:360, format=pix_fmts=yuv420p, fade=t=out:st=2.7:d=0.5:alpha=1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [va0];
[1:v] format=pix_fmts=yuv420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS + 3.2 / TB [va1];
[2:v] scale=640:-1, crop=640:360, trim=duration=147.768 [over];
[over][va0] overlay [over1];
[over1][va1] overlay=format=yuv420 [outv]
" -vcodec libx264 -map [outv] "Finished.mp4"
```

I want to add audio from "video.mp4"([1:a]) to the output starting a few seconds in, how do I go about this without causing a buffer overflow?

Thank you for your help in advance!

---

Edit, Adding ffmpeg output on request:

```
ffmpeg version N-66012-g97b8809 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep  1 2014 00:21:15 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.103 /  5.  0.103
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'C:\VideoApplicationAssets\test\logo.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 500x400 [SAR 9065:9065 DAR 5:4], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\VideoApplicationAssets\test\2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-03-07 04:36:36
  Duration: 00:02:24.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 574 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 475 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-07 04:36:36
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Input #2, lavfi, from 'color=black':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] 264 - core 142 r2479 dd79a61 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\VideoApplicationAssets\test\Finished.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.3.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> scale
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #2:0 (rawvideo) -> scale
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  149 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=      23kB time=00:00:03.23 bitrate=  57.6kbits/s    
frame=  240 fps=239 q=29.0 size=     200kB time=00:00:06.27 bitrate= 260.6kbits/s    
frame=  345 fps=229 q=29.0 size=     343kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate= 287.2kbits/s    
frame=  431 fps=215 q=29.0 size=     496kB time=00:00:12.64 bitrate= 321.1kbits/s    
frame=  502 fps=200 q=29.0 size=     633kB time=00:00:15.01 bitrate= 345.5kbits/s    
frame=  659 fps=219 q=29.0 size=     737kB time=00:00:20.25 bitrate= 298.0kbits/s    
frame=  843 fps=240 q=26.0 size=     790kB time=00:00:26.39 bitrate= 245.1kbits/s    
frame=  988 fps=246 q=29.0 size=     982kB time=00:00:31.23 bitrate= 257.7kbits/s    
frame= 1124 fps=249 q=29.0 size=    1200kB time=00:00:35.76 bitrate= 274.9kbits/s    
frame= 1292 fps=257 q=29.0 size=    1410kB time=00:00:41.37 bitrate= 279.3kbits/s    
frame= 1437 fps=260 q=29.0 size=    1773kB time=00:00:46.21 bitrate= 314.2kbits/s    
frame= 1565 fps=260 q=29.0 size=    2206kB time=00:00:50.48 bitrate= 358.0kbits/s    
frame= 1709 fps=262 q=29.0 size=    2542kB time=00:00:55.28 bitrate= 376.7kbits/s    
frame= 1872 fps=266 q=29.0 size=    2920kB time=00:01:00.72 bitrate= 393.9kbits/s    
frame= 2000 fps=265 q=29.0 size=    3157kB time=00:01:04.99 bitrate= 397.9kbits/s    
frame= 2108 fps=262 q=29.0 size=    3378kB time=00:01:08.60 bitrate= 403.4kbits/s    
frame= 2196 fps=257 q=29.0 size=    3592kB time=00:01:11.53 bitrate= 411.4kbits/s    
frame= 2291 fps=254 q=29.0 size=    3791kB time=00:01:14.70 bitrate= 415.7kbits/s    
frame= 2394 fps=251 q=29.0 size=    4013kB time=00:01:18.14 bitrate= 420.7kbits/s    
frame= 2492 fps=248 q=29.0 size=    4191kB time=00:01:21.41 bitrate= 421.7kbits/s    
frame= 2670 fps=253 q=29.0 size=    4323kB time=00:01:27.35 bitrate= 405.4kbits/s    
frame= 2829 fps=256 q=29.0 size=    4437kB time=00:01:32.65 bitrate= 392.3kbits/s    
frame= 2972 fps=257 q=29.0 size=    4749kB time=00:01:37.43 bitrate= 399.3kbits/s    
frame= 3143 fps=261 q=29.0 size=    5016kB time=00:01:43.13 bitrate= 398.4kbits/s    
frame= 3247 fps=259 q=29.0 size=    5430kB time=00:01:46.60 bitrate= 417.3kbits/s    
frame= 3396 fps=260 q=29.0 size=    5737kB time=00:01:51.57 bitrate= 421.2kbits/s    
frame= 3544 fps=262 q=29.0 size=    5995kB time=00:01:56.51 bitrate= 421.5kbits/s    
frame= 3691 fps=263 q=29.0 size=    6251kB time=00:02:01.42 bitrate= 421.7kbits/s    
frame= 3880 fps=267 q=29.0 size=    6342kB time=00:02:07.72 bitrate= 406.7kbits/s    
frame= 4059 fps=270 q=29.0 size=    6426kB time=00:02:13.70 bitrate= 393.7kbits/s    
frame= 4158 fps=267 q=29.0 size=    6699kB time=00:02:17.00 bitrate= 400.5kbits/s    
frame= 4309 fps=268 q=29.0 size=    6911kB time=00:02:22.04 bitrate= 398.6kbits/s    
frame= 4388 fps=265 q=29.0 size=    7187kB time=00:02:24.67 bitrate= 407.0kbits/s    
frame= 4430 fps=260 q=-1.0 Lsize=    7537kB time=00:02:27.74 bitrate= 417.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=2    

video:7491kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.618146%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] frame I:40    Avg QP:18.78  size: 22979
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] frame P:1964  Avg QP:22.33  size:  3056
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] frame B:2426  Avg QP:27.35  size:   309
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] consecutive B-frames: 24.5%  5.1%  6.6% 63.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] mb I  I16..4: 19.5% 35.8% 44.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] mb P  I16..4:  4.1%  5.7%  2.0%  P16..4: 24.4%  6.9%  2.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:54.5%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 11.1%  0.7%  0.1%  direct: 0.4%  skip:87.0%  L0:44.2% L1:52.6% BI: 3.2%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] 8x8 transform intra:45.7% inter:56.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 45.5% 44.9% 11.1% inter: 5.9% 6.3% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 39% 14% 23%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 24% 24%  3%  4%  4%  5%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 26% 14%  5%  7%  7%  7%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 22% 17%  4%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.6% UV:4.4%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] ref P L0: 79.1% 10.7%  8.3%  1.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] ref B L0: 92.1%  7.3%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] ref B L1: 94.8%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 000000000049cf60] kb/s:415.11
```

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` output from your command.

Comment: Is this also your question? [How to join two videos with a cross-fade effect using FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/questions/860940/how-to-join-two-videos-with-a-cross-fade-effect-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard No. But it appears we got our original command from the same place: 
http://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg